# Gigantic Memory Hog while loading training data

Tags: memory, machine-learning

I've been working on Person Identification via Voice, & I've succeeded in doing so. For training, I'm using ~500 wav files. I load these wav files, generate their MFCC's & store them in a vector. Therefore, after the training's done, I have ~500 vectors(each vector size is ~1000) loaded in the memory, which creates sort of a "Memory Hog". In order to save my memory, I could store all my training data in a file, which is a reasonable solution. I've tried it & it works fine. However, I wanted to know if there are any other procedures I can use which are even more efficient, and are used as standard practice while dealing in Machine Learning/Big Data?

Comment: How much memory do you use? On what platform? 500x1000 is not much on modern desktop's.

Comment: I am testing it on a PC, but I have plans to implement it using a DSP chip which has limited memory.

Comment: I see. Why do you need to store the training data on the DSP? Can't you just pre-train a model and then transfer it?

Comment: I can, and I will most probably. However, I just wanted to know about techniques which could make the system more efficient.

Comment: I don't understand your need to minimize this tiny amount of memory (~16mb with 32 bit floats) during training. You train a model on them, throw the MFCC's away, and transfer the learned model to your DSP.